# How to keep "Session" active after restarting NodeJS server?

Tags: node.js, express, npm, ejs, nodemon

Since I am using nodemon. After a tiny change on my source code, the server gets restart and I have to login again and again.
Is there any solution to keep the session alive after restarting the server?

Comment: Yes. Use a persistent session storage instead of a memory storage. Something like file store or mysql store will work. Personally from experience I'd recommend file store even for production websites

Comment: That sounds pretty good 

Comment: What are you using for your server? Express? Connect? Koa?

Comment: Sorry for being late on this reply. I am using Express JS... Any suggestions?

Comment: Look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/session-file-store. For more types of session storatge loop at this part of the documentation of express-session: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#compatible-session-stores